# TypeError: $(...).HSMegaMenu is not a function

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a problem in my javascript, when I try to run the page it always returns the next error and it does not load the components of the page.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).HSMegaMenu is not a function

My Code:

```
<script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      // initialization of HSMegaMenu component
      $('.js-mega-menu').HSMegaMenu({
        event: 'hover',
        pageContainer: $('.container'),
        breakpoint: 767,
        hideTimeOut: 0
      });
    });

    $(document).on('ready', function () {
      // initialization of header
      $.HSCore.components.HSHeader.init($('#header'));

      // initialization of unfold component
      $.HSCore.components.HSUnfold.init($('[data-unfold-target]'), {
        afterOpen: function () {
          $(this).find('input[type="search"]').focus();
        }
      });

      // initialization of forms
      $.HSCore.helpers.HSFocusState.init();

      // initialization of form validation
      $.HSCore.components.HSValidation.init('.js-validate');

      // initialization of fancybox
      $.HSCore.components.HSFancyBox.init('.js-fancybox');

      // initialization of slick carousel
      $.HSCore.components.HSSlickCarousel.init('.js-slick-carousel');

      // initialization of slick carousel
      $.HSCore.components.HSMalihuScrollBar.init($('.js-scrollbar'));

      // initialization of go to
      $.HSCore.components.HSGoTo.init('.js-go-to');
    });
  </script>
```

[Print error IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6rg1.png)

Comment: Have you imported the required scripts?

Comment: yes (y)
<script src="vendor/hs-megamenu/src/hs.megamenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/components/hs.header.js"></script>

Comment: how are you including the above script and the source library in the view ?

Comment: <script src="vendor/hs-megamenu/src/hs.megamenu.js"></script><script src="js/components/hs.header.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
 // initialization of HSMegaMenu component
  $(".js-mega-menu").HSMegaMenu({
    event: "hover",
    pageContainer: $(".container"),
    breakpoint: 1200,
    hideTimeOut: 0,
  });
});

$(document).on("ready", function () {
  // initialization of header
  $.HSCore.components.HSHeader.init($("#header"));

  // initialization of unfold component
  $.HSCore.components.HSUnfold.init($("[data-unfold-target]"), {
    afterOpen: function () {
      $(this).find('input[type="search"]').focus();
    },
  });

  // initialization of malihu scrollbar
  $.HSCore.components.HSMalihuScrollBar.init($(".js-scrollbar"));



// initialization of focus state
  $.HSCore.components.HSFocusState.init();

  // initialization of go to
  $.HSCore.components.HSGoTo.init(".js-go-to");

  // initialization of cubeportfolio
  //$.HSCore.components.HSCubeportfolio.init('.cbp');
});
```